# URL.decode not working witha a string

Tags: android

i have an image with an url that i need to put into an imageview so i tried URL.decode in order to get the right path because in my debug mode i get my url as :

```
"url":"https:\/\/cdn2.careerinsights.tv\/wpcontent\/uploads\/2014\/06\/capgemini-logo.jpg"}]}
```

but i'm still not getting the desired result

Here is my model :

```
public class Folder {
    public String dossierImage;
    public Folder(){}
    public String getDossierImage() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    return URLDecoder.decode(dossierImage, "UTF-8");;
    }
    public void setDossierImage(String dossierImage) {
        this.dossierImage = dossierImage;
    }
}
```

and here is where i make my call :

```
try {
    Picasso.get().load(s.getDossierImage()).into(dossierImage, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Picasso error!!");
        }
    });
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Add the code where you tried to decode the url @koreangirl.

Comment: i updatted my answer

Comment: Tell the exact url that contains the image ?

Comment: when i put an exact url directly in Picasso.get().load(), it works fine but when i get it from the database by Picasso.get().load(s.getDossierImage()), i need to decode it

Comment: Can you plz tell this is what you get from database "url":"https:\/\/cdn2.careerinsights.tv\/wpcontent\/uploads\/2014\/06\/capgemini-logo.jpg"}]}? And what is the result of url after decoding it ?

Comment: When i test it in postman, i get the url in the correct form but  once i make the call from android it become like that

Comment: Send the complete code at rajgar114@gmail.com